# Custom DialogFragment says my EditTexts are null

Tags: android, null, android-edittext, dialog

I'm definitely doing something wrong in the onCreateDialog(). The listener is working properly and I'm able to pass my host fragment Strings that I pass in, however, I'm getting errors saying my EditTexts are null. Also, I'm pretty new at coding so please forgive the mess.

Where am I supposed to get references to them from?

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


    builder.setTitle("Add Exercise");

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    final EditText name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ex_name);
    final EditText sets = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ex_sets);
    final EditText reps = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ex_reps);
    final EditText weight = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ex_weight);

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_exercise, null))
    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked Add button
            //listener.onDialogPositiveClick(AddExerciseDialogFragment.this);
            listener.getName(name.getText().toString().trim());
            listener.getName(name.getText().toString().trim());
            listener.getSets(Integer.parseInt(sets.getText().toString().trim()));
            listener.getReps(Integer.parseInt(reps.getText().toString().trim()));
            listener.getWeight(Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString().trim()));
            dismiss();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
            //listener.onDialogNegativeClick(AddExerciseDialogFragment.this);
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    //dialog.show();

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your EditTexts will always be null. That's because you're using findViewById on a view that doesn't contain them.
Pay atention on this line:

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_exercise, null))
```

You're inflating after you've already use findViewById. That's what's wrong.
First, get your view root layout:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_exercise, null);
```

Then, find your views:

```
EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Finally, after you've found all views you wish, use the main view root layout on your builder.

```
builder.setView(view)...
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't catch that. That solved my problem, thank you!!